# @(YES) vs [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, boolean, nsnumber

I am making a `HTTP` request in which I have to send a `bool` value. I tried with both of them.

And both are working in same way. I am confused which is better? and is their any difference between them?

Comment: "Better" for what?

Answer (score 5):

`@(YES)` is a literal for doing the same as `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`. I don't know whether the literals performance would be a bit slower as the direct call.

Answer (score 2):

One is a [literal](https://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/13/new-objectivec-literal-syntax/).  The other is created via a convienience initializer.

They end up being the same type of object with the same contents, but I suspect the first is easier for you (and other people looking at your code) to read.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the 2 methods, you should be fine with either. What I prefer though is `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` as it is more readable sometimes if you go back to your code for debugging. @(Yes) is the literal syntax for nsnumber, woks exactly the same when you use @"string" which creates NSString for you

Answer (score 2):

Nope.The compiler will transform `@YES` to `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`.

Answer (score 2):

@(YES) is the compiler characteristics. In fact, @(YES) converted to [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], there is no difference in performance.It is provided for convenience and readability (similar to @[], @{}).